# Scroll to view autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, scrollview

I'm using scrollView with auto layout. I followed thousands of tutorials, tips and explanations about it, but nothing seems to work, I'm almost going crazy.

```
What I am doing is the following:
-> View (main)
-> ScrollView
---> ContentView
----> Components

ScrollView margins = 0,  ContentView Margins = 0,  ContentView Center horizontal and vertical Center.
```

Add all correctly contraints, but scrollView not working scrolling, it's like he did not respect the height of the ContentView, and the result is as if there ouvesse no scroll on the screen.

How do I solve this? Someone pederia make a video or something of the genre? I visited almost all related links, and nothing works, I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `.contentSize` on the `UIScrollView` to be `contentView.frame.size`. Scroll views don't automatically know how much area to make scrollable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I've tried that and it did not work [scroll setContentSize: contentView.frame.size];